# IoC: ProjectReference with ReferenceOutputAssembly = false, but still want nuget packages

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, msbuild, nuget, autofac

**Background**

I'm looking to copy dll's from my data access tier into my application tier for the purposes of AutoFac to load up the dlls, however don't wish there to be a project reference so a developer cannot accidentally reference & use a data access tier class directly.

**The problem**

I have something like this in my Application Tier csproj file.

This has been working great, but I have now realised that it's not copying the transient dependencies i.e. the nuget packages

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyProj.csproj">
  <!-- We don't wish a developer to accidentally reference the DAL tier directly in the UI, only as a dependency. -->
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
  <!-- As the composite root (in DI terms) we still want to ensure that the UI tier has a copy of the DAL dll to load up.-->
  <OutputItemType>Content</OutputItemType>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <!-- DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup copies PDB files, but not for Visual Studio, which is still fine as Visual Studio knows how to get debugging information.  -->
  <Targets>Build;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup</Targets>
</ProjectReference>
```

Along with:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Reading through swarms of github tickets and blogs, a few for example:

https://www.erikheemskerk.nl/transitive-nuget-dependencies-net-core-got-your-back/

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6151

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/747

And playing with everything combination I can think of, doesn't seem to copy the nuget packages.

The only way which works is:

```
<ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
```

Which sort of defeats the objective of keeping the data access tier dll away from the application tier.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your own custom copy target to copy over what you want. Nothing wrong with that. And then you should be able to remove the ProjectReference shown above.

Comment: Thanks, I was wary if doing that then I wouldn't get any warnings about sub-dependencies with differing versions? Assuming I would get said warnings if using a build in ProjectReference technique?